# Is there a term for speaking English with a foreign accent to make it easier for foreigners to understand?

Tags: speech, accent

I was just recalling [Joey Barton's interview with the French media](http://www.theguardian.com/football/video/2012/nov/26/joey-barton-english-french-accent-video) in which he speaks with a French accent, seemingly to make it easier for his audience to understand.

As humourous as it may be, is there a term for this?

Comment: In Danish, I would say he's doing them a ‘bear’s favour’ (_bjørnetjeneste_), which means that he's actually doing them a disservice, even though he does it with the best of intentions and thinks he's doing them a favour. Can't think of an expression for that in English, and I don't think that's really what you're looking for, anyway.

Comment: Nope. That is not what he is looking for, you are doing him a disservice ;)

Comment: I was under the impression that for foreigners to understand English, you merely have to speak _MORE LOUDLY_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon an article today and was reminded of the term I was looking for.

***["speech accommodation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_accommodation_theory#Speech_accommodation_theory)***

And some [interesting reading](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Accommodation.htm) on the matter.

> Accommodation most often takes the form of convergence, when a speaker chooses a language variety that seems to fit the style of the other speaker.

Answer (score 2):

***An [affected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affect) accent*** comes to mind which does not cover the reason behind the accent

Comment: or *affecting* his speech.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd say 'putting on a fake accent'.

Comment: "Personally" makes it a comment. Please wait until you have earned enough rep to post comments. This may now get deleted or converted to a comment.